# Bash script & PostgreSQL: How to access column values returned from SELECT statement

Tags: sql, bash, postgresql

I have a database in PostgreSQL called customers, customers has a table called CustomerInfo. CustomerInfo contains 3 columns ID, Name and address. I would like to write a bash script to get the information from the CustomerInfo table but i am not sure how to access the individual rows once i have the results of the query. Here is the script i have written:

```
#!/bin/bash  

results=`psql -d customers -c "select * from CustomerInfo where name = 'Dave'"`

echo $results['name']
```

The query runs correctly and returns the correct results but the echo command will just print everything in results. I know this is not the correct way of doing this, does anyone know of a way to get the query results as an array, or would i just have to write my own function for parsing the results?

Thanks!

Comment: The effort needed to do that sort of thing with bash is better spent learning Perl basics.

Comment: Before trying to write anything yourself you have to realize what you are doing here: Executing a command and storing its output(text) in a variable. Therefore you would need to parse and disassemble that text in order to make this thing work.

Answer (score 9):

You can store your results into an array and loop through it using a while loop.

```
psql -d customers -c "select * from CustomerInfo where name = 'Dave'"
| while read -a Record ; do
    # ${Record[0]} is your ID field
    # ${Record[1]} is your Name field
    # ${Record[2]} is your address field
done
```

Comment: If you'd like to only iterate over the values (and not the header describing the column) add a -t to the psql command.

Comment: Am I doing something wrong I just get the entire row to end up in `${Record[0]}`. It looks like `1|ed393959-6c5f-4f79-a9b9-11516c3c8990|Recordblabla|2021-06-16`

Answer (score 8):

I had success using the

```
psql | while read do
```

approach:

```
$PG_HOME/bin/psql \
-h 127.0.0.1 \
-U $DB_USER \
-c 'SELECT recipient_email, name FROM report_recipients' \
--set ON_ERROR_STOP=on \
--no-align \
--quiet \
--no-password \
--tuples-only \
--field-separator ' ' \
--pset footer=off \
--dbname=$DATABASE \
| while read EMAIL_ADDRESS NAME   ; do
    echo "$SCRIPT: addr=$EMAIL_ADDRESS  name=$NAME"
done
```

There is a great resource for this and similar things at: [manniwood.com's PostgreSQL and bash Stuff page](http://www.manniwood.com/postgresql_and_bash_stuff/index.html)

Comment: Get a strange error on above approach trying to pipe the psql output to while:

line 18: syntax error at line 31: `|' unexpected

For reference the relevant line:
```
$PSQL \
    -X \
    -h $host \
    -U $username \
    -c "$id_sql" \
    --single-transaction \
    --set AUTOCOMMIT=off \
    --set ON_ERROR_STOP=on \
    --no-align \
    -t \
    --field-separator ' ' \
    --dbname $dbname \
    --quiet
| while read id_num name ; do
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You have to write your own function for paring the query results. Backtick( ` ) will execute the command and returns the output.
In your case, results will have output of your query.

Answer (score -2):

If I were tasked with doing this (really, Perl is better, take the advice of @daniel-verite), here is what I would do.

1. Get a list of column names by piping the initial results through `head`
2. Create a function which parses the rest using awk into a useful format.
3. sed or awk to extract the relevant information from a row.

Now, the above assumes no embedded newlines (which would complicate things)

This amount of effort is anything but trivial.  You really are better off learning Perl for a task like this.